# SIGABRT crash on __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a SIGABRT crash log that is unfamiliar to me.  Looks like it's throwing an exception, but I can't see where the exception is listed or the root cause of it.

This is running on a customer's iPad 2 / iOS 4.3.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33ed3a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x354d83b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x354d0bf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33671a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3636906c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3366fe36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3366fe8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3366ff5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36367c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   Foundation                      0x33f69924 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 648
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33e4ba72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33e4d758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33e4e4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33ddeebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33ddedc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
15  GraphicsServices                0x33544418 GSEventRunModal + 108
16  GraphicsServices                0x335444c4 GSEventRun + 56
17  UIKit                           0x34416d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
18  UIKit                           0x34414800 UIApplicationMain + 664
19  MyApp                           0x000190c4 main (main.m:14)
20  MyApp                           0x0001907c 0x18000 + 4220
```

Where would I start looking to diagnose this?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and see if that gives you any more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program should print information about the exception to the device console (viewable in the Xcode organizer when the device is connected).  It would be very, very helpful to see this information.

`_NSThreadPerformPerform` is used by the `performSelector...` family of methods.  So look at your use of those methods.  In particular, figure out if it's possible that you're asking an object to perform a selector that it doesn't support.  That would throw an exception.