# A very interesting crash log with Exception Type:"EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)"

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault, cfrunloop

Firstly, the desymbolicated crash log is at the bottom. I cannot post all the content out of privacy reason. However the first 3 threads log is enough I thought, if you really want that please leave a message.

And here is the thing, depending on this article [Understanding iOS Exception Types | 5Neo.Be5Neo.Be](http://www.5neo.be/understanding-ios-exception-types/), the mach exception type -- **EXC_CRASH** -- is not usual following with the C signal **SIGSEGV** (which means access an address you don't own).

So I want to know what reason or when will **EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)** appear?

Second question is if this crash is actually trigger by Thread 0 as the log said. And if it's ture, then what does

**"__NSThreadPerformPerform"**

and

**"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__"**

means?

What action is system doing? By the way, **__NSThreadPerformPerform** will appear when App call "performSelector:" method according to this answer -- [iphone - SIGABRT crash on **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214721/sigabrt-crash-on-cfrunloop-is-calling-out-to-a-source0-perform-function).

Thanks.

-- Crash log is here: --

```
{"name":"XXXApp","bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1 (11D201)","bundleID":"com.xxx","version":"6.7.1.0 (6.7.1)","app_name":"XXXApp"}
Incident Identifier: EC2DC883-C0DB-4FD6-81FB-237626598366
CrashReporter Key:   d5c091bc35732df06fcaf41e5786833159b04ea5
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             XXXApp [1912]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/4E3E131C-5847-4B61-A0E0-D350830C1693/BaiduBoxApp.app/XXXApp
Identifier:          com.xxx
Version:             6.7.1.0 (6.7.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-28 00:37:32.658 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39c636d8 __kill + 8
1   Foundation                      0x2f901c1e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2eee3fec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2eee34b2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2eee1ca2 __CFRunLoopRun + 626
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee4c764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee4c546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
7   GraphicsServices                0x33db96ce GSEventRunModal + 134
8   UIKit                           0x317ab88c UIApplicationMain + 1132
9   BaiduBoxApp                     0x0006d13e main (main.m:17)
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x39badab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39c51804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39ba0050 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39b9a2de _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39c51a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39c51848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2eee3624 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2eee1d44 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee4c764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2ee4c546 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2f88c23c +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316
7   Foundation                      0x2f901a0a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ccb956 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ccb8c6 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39cc9ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39c64434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2eee751e __CFSocketManager + 482
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ccb956 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ccb8c6 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39cc9ae4 thread_start + 4

...
```

Comment: There's nothing really obvious.  You'll need to reproduce the crash with the debugger attached.

Comment: Since it's a user uploaded crash log, we actually couldn't reproduce this crash. But because as a large number of users app, I must consider to solve crash like this.

Comment: I have google it for a long time, and I want to find is there somebody else have similar issue as mine. And I want to know if anybody know the system called methods actrually do.

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214721/sigabrt-crash-on-cfrunloop-is-calling-out-to-a-source0-perform-function

Comment: @johnykumar Thx~ I have seen that answer before, but I also want to get more information about that. I know it's a bit of harsh but maybe there somebody can share more.